# Closure of an interval in specific topology

Tags: general-topology

Given a topology constructed on elements of the type

$$
(p,q] 
$$

where $p$ and $q$ are rational numbers. Let us call this topology $\tau_{-,Q}$, given an interval of type $(a,b]$ its closure in the topology $\tau_{-,Q}$ is $[a, +\infty)$.

I have two questions:

1) Why the right limit of the closure is $+\infty$?

2) How can we compare $\tau_{-,Q}$ with standard topology based on the opened intervals of real numbers?

Please someone can suggest to me a sketch of proof or some references for understanding this particular exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.  Let $c>a,b$. Then there are rational $p,q$ such that $b<p<c\le q$. Now $(p,q]$ is a neighborhood of $c$ and $(a,b]\cap(p,q]=\emptyset$.  So, $c$ is not a limit point nor an element $(a,b]$ and so is not in the closure.

Comment: Moreover, $a$ is in the closure of $(a,b]$ iff $a$ is irrational.